# Using Adobe fonts with newpx in pdftex

Tags: fonts

Over a decade ago I've purchased the Palatino Expert Fonts, i.e., pplbij8a, pplbj8a, pplrc8a, and pplrij8, that is Palatino-BoldItalicOsF, Palatino-BoldOsF, Palatino-SC, and Palatino-ItalicOsF. May I substitute the corresponding fonts of newpx by those original ones?  And if so: how?

Which encoding should I use? 8r.enc displays some characters wrongly.

Here's what I (naively) tried:

Replaced

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{zpltosf}{m}{it}{<-> \zpl@scaled zpl-Italic-tosf-t1}{}
```

by

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{zpltosf}{m}{it}{<-> pplrij8r}{}
```

where the corresponding entry in the map-file is

```
pplrij8r Palatino-ItalicOsF " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <pplrij8a.pfb
```

But then `germandbls` is replaced by `ydieresis` and the fi-ligature and others are just don't show up.

Comment: Do you mean that you have `.ttf` files for these fonts ?

Comment: Well, I have the .pfb.

Comment: Have a look at this page http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/fonts.html. There is a section on *Using Postscript fonts in LaTeX*. Hope it helps

Comment: This for that link, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Could detail your problem a bit and how you obtain it ?